# Displaying SET variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

can i see the value of variable using ECHO command? I tried this way but didn't work.

```
@echo off
set _src = String
echo %_src%
pause
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the spaces out either side of your equals sign and this should work.